# How can I do a distinct sum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a "score" statistic which is derived from the value of a certain column, calculated as the sum of a case expression. Unfortunately, the query structure needs to be a full outer join (this is simplified from the actual query, and the join structure survives from the original code), and thus the sum is incorrect, since each row may occur many times. I could group by the unique key; however, that breaks other aggregate functions that are in the same query.

What I really want to do is sum (case when ... distinct claim_id) which of course does not exist; is there an approach that will do what I need? Or does this have to be two queries?

This is on redshift, in case it matters.

```
create table t1 (id int, proc_date date, claim_id int, proc_code char(1));
create table t2 (id int, diag_date date, claim_id int);

insert into t1 (id, proc_date, claim_id, proc_code)
values (1, '2012-01-01', 0, 'a'),
(2, '2009-02-01', 1, 'b'),
(2, '2019-02-01', 2, 'c'),
(2, '2029-02-01', 3, 'd'),
(3, '2016-04-02', 4, 'e'),
(4, '2005-01-03', 5, 'f'),
(5, '2008-02-03', 6, 'g');

insert into t2 (id, diag_date, claim_id)
values (4, '2004-01-01', 20),
(5, '2010-02-01', 21),
(6, '2007-04-02', 22),
(5, '2011-02-01', 23),
(6, '2008-04-02', 24),
(5, '2012-02-01', 25),
(6, '2009-04-02', 26),
(7, '2002-01-03', 27),
(8, '2001-02-03', 28);

select id, sum(case when proc_code='a' then 5
         when proc_code='b' then 10
         when proc_code='c' then 15
         when proc_code='d' then 20
         when proc_code='e' then 25
         when proc_code='f' then 30
         when proc_code='g' then 35 end), count(distinct t1.claim_id) as proc_count, min(proc_date) as min_proc_date

from t1 full outer join t2 using (id) group by id order by id;
```

Comment: You could add `else 0` to the `case when` to get rid of the `null` values in the sum, I think `0` is more suitable there. And you could probably even do it without case when with something like: `(ASCII(proc_code) - ASCII('a') + 1) * 5`

Comment: @maraca Not sure what you're getting at, but `NULL` is ignored by aggregate functions. `0` vs `NULL` has no impact on a `SUM()`

Comment: @HartCO execute your query, you will get `NULL` values in the `SUM` column, in my opinion the sum should be `0` then, for the min_date it is ok when it is NULL. It is a problem when there is no value at all to sum because all are NULL.

Comment: @maraca That's true, I was just confused because I thought you were suggesting it was part of the problem the OP has run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate out your conditional aggregates into a `cte` or subquery and use `OVER(PARTITION BY id)` to get an `id` level aggregate without grouping, something like this:

```
with cte AS (SELECT *,sum(case when proc_code='a' then 5
                               when proc_code='b' then 10
                               when proc_code='c' then 15
                               when proc_code='d' then 20
                               when proc_code='e' then 25
                               when proc_code='f' then 30
                               when proc_code='g' then 35 end) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS Some_Sum                  
                  , min(proc_date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as min_proc_date
             FROM t1
             )
select id
     , Some_Sum
     , count(distinct cte.claim_id) as proc_count
     , min_proc_date
from cte 
full outer join t2 using (id) 
group by id,Some_Sum,min_proc_Date 
order by id;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/95310/6/1)

Note that you'll have to add these aggregates to the `GROUP BY` in the outer query, and the fields in your `PARTITION BY` should match the `t1` fields you previously used in `GROUP BY`, in this case just `id`, but if your full query had other `t1` fields in the `GROUP BY` be sure to add them to the `PARTITION BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery (by id and id_claim) and then regroup:

```
with base as (
select id, avg(case when proc_code='a' then 5
         when proc_code='b' then 10
         when proc_code='c' then 15
         when proc_code='d' then 20
         when proc_code='e' then 25
         when proc_code='f' then 30
         when proc_code='g' then 35 end) as value_proc, 
         t1.claim_id , min(proc_date) as min_proc_date
  from t1 full outer join t2 using (id) group by id, t1.claim_id order by id, t1.claim_id) 
 select id, sum(value_proc), count(distinct claim_id) as proc_count,  min(min_proc_date) as min_proc_date
   from base
   group by id
   order by id;
```

See that I sugest `avg` for the internal subquery, but if you are sure that the same claim_id have the same letter you can use `max` or `min` and that was integer. If not is prefer this.